# How do I split Flask models out of app.py without passing db object all over?

Tags: python, flask, flask-migrate

I'd like to use [Flask-Migrate](https://flask-migrate.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) and am looking at their example:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask.ext.script import Manager
from flask.ext.migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///app.db'

db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

This works great as a simple play example, but I have more than a single model and I don't want to define the models in both this script and the one that defines my application code. Thus, I want to pull them into a model file that I can share between the two.

I attempting to do this, by placing the `User` class into a `models.py` and then importing User from there. Unfortunately, that throws a `NameError: name 'db' is not defined`.

My question(s) are:

- Do I need to use `db = SQLAlchemy(app)` in my `models.py`, and if so will this be available in both my migration script and the flask application itself?
- If I can't (or shouldn't) put it in `models.py`, how do I utilize my models in their own file without passing `db` all over?

Comment: Check this out https://realpython.com/blog/python/python-web-applications-with-flask-part-ii/

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Partitioning such a small application into modules is tricky, because you find a lot of cases where the two modules that you create need to mutually import each other, creating circular dependencies.

I recommend that you look at how you can structure a larger application properly, using an app factory function and delayed initialization of all extensions. An example application that does this is the [Flasky](https://github.com/miguelgrinberg/flasky) app featured in my book.

All that said, it is possible to separate the application into two parts, you just need to be careful with where you place the import statements. In the example below, I decided to move the creation of the `db` instance and the `User` model into a models.py file.

Here is the main application's module:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.script import Manager
from flask.ext.migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///app.db'

from models import db  # <-- this needs to be placed after app is created
migrate = Migrate(app, db)

manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

And here is models.py:

```
from __main__ import app
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(128))
```

Here the main module will create `app`, and only then will import models.py. When models.py tries to import `app` from the main module, it has already been created. If you move `from models import db` to the top of the file with the other imports this code breaks.

Comment: I understand your example but what if what I want is to split models.py into different .pys? for example User.py, Foo.py, Bar.py. I'm struggling to find a way to do that.

Comment: @VitorHugo you can create a `models` package, create  `db` instance in the package's `__init__.py` file, then add one module per model, with all these modules importing the `db` instance as `from . import db`.

Comment: That worked but when I do a db.create_all() on the main application module after the 'from models import db' it does not create the tables which is what happens when I do models.py. Should that be a separated thing or should I worry about it?

Comment: You have to import all the models before you call `db.create_all()`.

Comment: I thought there would be some cyclical problem and not work but it did. Thank you very much sir.

Comment: To use the `User` model is it also necessary to `from models import User` in  the main module?

Comment: Yes, you would also import `User` in the same place where `db` is imported.

Comment: It would be great to see the code for the working solution with a `models` package.

Comment: I Know the answer is old, but I just had a problem with it: it doesn't work on production servers, such as unicorn, since each app is not in "__main__". Looking for an answer now...

Answer (score 2):

Here is an idea. You can create a package `model` in which you define classes as individual `.py` files. For example, `user.py` contains the `User` class.

In the `__init__.py` file you can define the `db` variable. You may also include `from user import User` statement so that it would be possible to access `User` object directly outside the package. For example you can import the `model` package somewhere else in the program using `import model` and then use `model.User` to directly use the `User` class.

To use `db` variable directly in the `user.py` use `from ..model import db` which imports `db` variable defined in the `__init__.py` file.

Comment: Doesn't this mean that I then need to pass `app` (from `db = SQLAlchemy(app)`) around instead of `db`?

Comment: Well, in that case you can add both `app` and `db` in `__init__.py`

Comment: @aliasm2k The whole point of the `model` module is to seperate model from app. Putting them both in package __init__ provides no looser coupling than keeping them in the single module.

Answer (score 0):

Your answer was very helpful for me. I finally grasped the rather cumbersome python importing rules. Here I try to illustrate the pattern in a cleaner way (by "cleaner" I mean not complicated with additional issues, like those on migration). This is the simple and common case of partitioning and app into a main module and a secondary module which just declare the database models.

main:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request, url_for, redirect
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__) # this is a key point

app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///clientes.sqlite3'
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS'] = False 
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = "random string"

from fasiDB import db, Corr, Cliente, Producto # db and models

# here come the various routes which access db
```

models:

```
from __main__ import app
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

db = SQLAlchemy(app) # the argument "app" comes from main

class Corr(db.Model):
    id = db.Column('corr_id', db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    nf = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

...

```
class Cliente(db.Model):
   id = db.Column('cliente_id', db.Integer, primary_key = True)
   nombre = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
   rSocial = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
   ruc = db.Column(db.String(27), unique=True)
   dir = db.Column(db.String(100))
```

...